# How to make pop up show up after the fields of the form are fulfilled?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a website for a project and I've added a subscribe to our newsletter section and I've set up a pop when you click the subscribe button. Before I added that js, the form wouldn't proceed until both fields were filled out and it showed a popup telling you to fill it.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" required>
<input type="text" placeholder="Email address" name="mail" required>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="subscribe"> Daily 
Newsletter
</label>

<input type="submit" value="Subscribe" onclick="myFunction1()">
```

Now with the js, it shows the pop up I made thanking the person for subscribing when I click the subscribe button regardless if the fields are filled or not.

```
function myFunction1() {
    alert("Thanks for subscribing!")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside the function check for the field values. Confirm whether the fields are empty. If not then show the alert

```
function myFunction1() {
  var f1 = ; // get value of field1;
  var f2 = ; // get value of field2;
  if (f1 != '' && f2 != ''){
      alert("Thanks for subscribing!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should include all the inputs in a form tag, as so:

```
<form id='myForm'>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" required>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email address" name="mail" required>
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="subscribe"> Daily 
    Newsletter
    </label>

    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" onclick="myFunction1()">
</form>
```

This approach is better because then all the inputs are together in one entity, without it the 'submit' input won't really work. It won't know what is being submitted. Within the form tag it knows it's submitting the form together with all inputs contained within.

The form tag has its own set of events that you can add listeners to. 
Including a 'submit' event.

To add the event listener to run your function whenever a submit happens on the form, you can do as so:

```
document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', myFunction1)
```

Alternatively, you can also set the listener on the html:

```
<form onsubmit='myFunction1()'>
```

But keep in mind that with the 'addEventListener' method you can add multiple listeners to the same event. While the onsubmit property only accepts one function.

More info on events and on the addEventListener method:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

give all inputs of class, eg: 'myInput', and loop over them to check their value before alerting.

```
function myFunction1() {

    var inputs = Array.fom(document.getElementsByClassName('myInput'));
    var allChecked = false;

    inputs.map(function(input){
        if (input.value == '') { allChecked = false }
    });

    if (allChecked) { alert("Thanks for subscribing!") }
};
```